# Python: How do I use tuples in lists?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this code that doesn't work the way I expect it to. I'm trying to make a grid. It should output the tuple from the list, but it's stuck on the first number.

Is there a problem with my logic?

```
row = []
grid = []

for y in range(0,3):
    row.append((0,0))

for x in range(0,3):
    grid.append(row)


for y in range(0, 3):
    for x in range (0, 3):
        print (x,y)
        grid[x][y] = (x,y)
        print (grid[x][y])

print ("\nTesting:")
for y in range(0, 3):
    for x in range (0, 3):
        print (grid[x][y])
```

What it outputs is this:

```
0 0
(0, 0)
1 0
(1, 0)
2 0
(2, 0)
0 1
(0, 1)
1 1
(1, 1)
2 1
(2, 1)
0 2
(0, 2)
1 2
(1, 2)
2 2
(2, 2)

Testing:
(2, 0)
(2, 0)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 1)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 2)
(2, 2)
```

Comment: Is the testing part your desired output?

Comment: Yes. I just put that in to show what it outputs.

Comment: Ah, the old mutable variable gotcha. Let me find the dupe link.

Comment: Related, but not quite a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this:

```
for x in range(0,3):
    grid.append(row)
```

Keep in mind that `row` is the *name* that refers to a particular list. By executing this line of code multiple times, you're adding *the same list* to `grid` multiple times. In other words, `grid[0]`, `grid[1]`, and `grid[2]` are all pointing to the same piece of memory.

As such, when you modify the list that all three are pointing at, then all three will display the changes.

To avoid this you need to make a copy of the list when inserting it, so you're not inserting the same object multiple times (just copies of the same object). The easiest way to do this is to make a blank slice:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    grid.append(row[:])
```

Comment: Ahh! I knew there was some trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's because tuples are hashable, so you would have to copy those objects:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    grid.append(row.copy())
```

Comment: Tuples are not mutable.  `Row` is a list, and lists are mutable.

Comment: @Acccumulation Sorry I meant hashable, and also immutable, it was my typo